# Failed Audit - First Posts

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed an audit with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17047090) post. I have no idea about python, but I think OP was indeed trying to post a solution that genuinely worked for him.

Other than removing the "Good day" salutation and a few backticks there was no other edit that I felt necessary (those edits usually get rejected for being too trivial). And I did not feel the answer merited a downvote.

If that answer actually worked for the user then does it really deserve to be closed?

Comment: _I have no idea about python_ Some advice, skip questions regarding Python, unless it's obviously bad then you won't run into this issue. I skip questions regarding various languages as they're better reviewed by people you have the understanding of that language. As for your review, I can't help you as I don't know about Python ^.^

Comment: Personally I feel it is an attempt to answer even if they have nabbed something from a comment. Bad audit IMO. That said, it does look like a poor answer so would merit downvotes.

Comment: IMO it is a bad-ish audit but you could do a pretty big edit there.  Everything before *So I changed the user to root for nginx and finally, it worked.* could be edited out and the rest could be reworded.  I'm not sure it edit fails or not but that is what I would have done.

Comment: @George You don't need domain knowledge to review first posts.  There's no reason at all to skip (most) posts just because you're not familiar with the technology.

Comment: Also consider phrases like, *is not working for me* or *I had the same problem* or anything similar to be a red flag that you should check to make sure the answer still exists. A lot of answers like this get flagged as not an answer because they think that the user is asking a new question even when the OP goes on to explain how they solved the issue when they encountered it. As Servy said, if the answer hasn't been deleted, you'd be doing the OP a service by editing such phrases out.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. After reading all the responses I have to conclude that I made a bad call. I should have added a comment in the very least.

Comment: *I have no idea about XXX* then why do you think you are qualified to judge an answer on it that is not just gibberish? `Skip` is an option for a reason!

Comment: Point taken @JarrodRoberson . I realize now that it was a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you don't think that answer needed to be deleted, it still has major problems that need to be addressed.  There's the salutations, as you mentioned, there's code not formatted as code, there's lots of entirely unnecessary information (like saying, "doing X didn't work for me"; that's not answering the question, saying why it *wouldn't* work might be useful, saying that it didn't work for you is just commentary on another answer), along with the framework versions.

The answer is also poorly structured (which is why it appears to be a non-answer); it should really be re-worked so that it actually looks like an answer.  On a first reading it looks like it's just commentary on another's answer, rather than actually providing an original answer, and re-wording the answer could prevent it from being misunderstood.

Finally, the answer is also just not particularly good quality in that it doesn't explain anything, (and it reads to me like the author doesn't even understand it themselves, which is worrying), so if you *do* think that the answer has potential, you should really be commenting to try to get the author to add some explanation for why this change solves the problem.

So all in all, saying "no action needed" here is pretty clearly wrong.  There's lots to do here, even if you don't think the answer should be deleted.

Comment: "Doing X didn't work for me" is information, I'd like to keep that. If nothing else, it might turn up in search results for people who also tried using X, and are looking for an alternative.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Like I said, that's information that's commentary on another answer.  If you think it's useful information, post it as a *comment on that answer*, not in a new answer.  But even then, "it didn't work for me" adds almost nothing, unlike, "this answer can't work, or only sometimes works, because of X", which is actually quite useful.